# How rewrite value of custom cookie created in functions.php?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I added my custom cookie in `functions.php` :

```
add_action( 'init', 'setCustomCookie' );

function setCustomCookie()
{
  setcookie('custom-cookie', true, time() + (86400 * 21), '/');
}
```

and I need to change value in JS after clicking on button:

```
$ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#against_more').click(function (evt) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var myCookie = getCookie("custom-cookie");

        // I tried setCookie and etc. nothing was succesfull

    })
});
```

Is possible to do that, please??

Comment: Have you checked if cookie set in `setCustomCookie`?

Comment: yes, I checked, but I found better way with "document.cookie". It offers me easily check and rewrite value